# Adding HTML rectangles with for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to draw a 2 x 2 grid of blue rectangles on an HTML page, but my code does not draw anything. I create a fragment toAdd that I want to add later, and add divs to toAdd. I'm not quite sure where I went wrong, and when I tried to add a console.log() I could confirm that addSquares is being called. Do I need to add anything to the HTML file, or is there a mistake in this code?

I also noticed that this code produces five divs: b0, b1, b2, b3, b1 (returns error) and I'm not sure what is wrong with my for loop.

```
dim = 2;
width = 50;
height = 50;

// add the squares 
function addSquares()
{
  var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for(var i = 0; i < dim; i++)
  {
    for(var j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
      var label = j + i * dim; 
      var name = "b" + label;
      console.log(name)
      var div = document.createElement(name);
      div.style.width = width + "px";
      div.style.height = height + "px";
      div.style.left = width * j + "px";
      div.style.top = height * i + "px";
      div.style.position = "absolute";
      div.style.color = "blue";
      toAdd.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
  document.appendChild(toAdd);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that there's two issues. The first being that you need to change:

```
document.appendChild(toAdd);
```

to

```
document.body.appendChild(toAdd);
```

Your second issue is that your using the wrong CSS styling declaration. Your divs are in the DOM but don't have a `backgroundColor` assigned to them, which in turn gives the illusion that they're not there. So instead of `color` use `backgroundColor`.

```js
dim = 2;
width = 50;
height = 50;

// add the squares 
function addSquares()
{
  var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for(var i = 0; i < dim; i++)
  {
    for(var j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
      var label = j + i * dim; 
      var name = "b" + label;
      console.log(name)
      var div = document.createElement(name);
      div.style.width = width + "px";
      div.style.height = height + "px";
      div.style.left = width * j + "px";
      div.style.top = height * i + "px";
      div.style.position = "absolute";
      div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      toAdd.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
  document.body.appendChild(toAdd);
}

addSquares();
```

Comment: I tried this but the rectangles still did not show up

Comment: Updated my answer. Take a look and let me know if that addresses your problem.

Comment: Yes this worked!! Thank you!
Quick question-- if I want to append these rectangle to a container, and I want to call something on the rectangles (I am writing a function that adds an event listener to each rectangle), am I able to call them by name?

Comment: Glad to hear! Don't forget to mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Do you mind answering one last question? If I want to append these rectangle to a container, and I want to call something on the rectangles (I am writing a function that adds an event listener to each rectangle), am I able to call them by name?

Comment: Yeah. Hypothetically you would just have to do add an event listener to the divs within your loop.

Answer (score -1):

I just wanted to point out a little trick to you...

You have this:

```
div.style.width = width + "px";
div.style.height = height + "px";
div.style.left = width * j + "px";
div.style.top = height * i + "px";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

I believe can be written like this ES6:

```
div.style.cssText =  `width: ${width + "px"}; 
                      height: ${height + "px"}; 
                      left: ${width * j + "px"}; 
                      top: ${height * i + "px"}; 
                      position: absolute; 
                      backgroundColor: blue;`
```

As far as I know .cssText = will replace the existing inline...

To append the existing inline use .cssText +=

I'm sure this will help you in the long run.